# Conditionally add a class if a specific string is found Rails CoffeeScript

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a simple ruby on rails app and am trying to have the table rows colored if they have a status of "Pending". The code below is from my application.js coffeescript file, but doesn't function.

```
    $(document).ready ->
        if $('td:contains(\'Pending\')')
            @parent('tr').addClass 'warning'
        return
```

Comment: Comment cancelled. My apologies.

Comment: Ok, so another developer suggested I add a class to my <tr> within the index.html.erb file and then add css styles accordingly. Now I have the code: `<tr class="<%= order_summary.status.underscore %>">`  but I'm getting this error: undefined method `underscore' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend entering like the following:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("td:contains('Pending')").parent().addClass('warning')
```

**Edit**

Ok, by doing the following:

```
addWarningClassToPending = ->
  $("td:contains('Pending')").parent().addClass('warning')

$(document).ready(addWarningClassToPending)
```

you can set `addWarningClassToPending` as a callback function for another event.

Comment: Wow that works beautifully. The only catch is it works on the first time the page loads. If I navigate to a new object and back, the styling doesn't show unless I refresh the page. Thanks for the help though. Definitely in the right direction.

Comment: This seems to be working for me: `$(document).bind 'DOMSubtreeModified', (e) ->
  $('td:contains(\'Pending\')').parent().addClass 'warning'
  return`